# Let $a$, $x$ and $y$ be real numbers and let $\varepsilon > 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a$, $x$ and $y$ be real numbers and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Suppose that $|x-a|< \varepsilon$ and $|y-a|< \varepsilon$. Use the triangle inequality to find an estimation for the magnitude of $|x-y|$.

Answer (score 2):

$|x-y|\le |x-a|+|a-y|<\epsilon +\epsilon =2\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $|x-y|=|x-a+a-y|=|(x-a)+(a-y)|$, apply the triangle inequality.